# Get the first entry of a JSON object

Tags: php, json

Facebook gives a JSON stream like this:

```
 "actions": [
    {
       "name": "Comment",
       "link": "http://www.facebook.com/100000335233539/posts/193845507303289"
    },
    {
       "name": "Like",
       "link": "http://www.facebook.com/100000335233539/posts/193845507303289"
    },
    {
       "name": "Read entire article",
       "link": "http://www.domain.tld/article/"
    }
 ],
```

I want to get the first of the three objects with:

```
$link = ($feeditem['actions']['link']);
```

But I always get only the last entry.
How can I get the first one?

Comment: I think you also need `->link`, not `['link']`.

Comment: In PHP use  ->link instead of ['link']
Question seems to be a python question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
$actions[0]['link']
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked with `$link = ($feeditem['actions'][0]['link']);`

Comment: You don't need the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it (useful for when things are objects without nice numeric indexes, not arrays):

```
foreach($feeditem['actions'] as $action) {
  $link = $action->link;
  break;
}
```